# CakePHP Based News Site With Photos, Videos, and Social Interaction

Tags: php, cakephp, video, photos

First of all, I have done some research in finding out what best to do when developing a large-scale website that basically encompasses everything such as News, Fotos, Videos and User Interaction, but I still feel I need more inputs from other developers.

I currently run a portuguese (Cape Verde) based website using PHPCow ([Brava News Network](http://www.bravanews.com)), 4images for fotos, separately. I feel that it is about time to change and approach it in a different manner by developing my own app that is uniform. I have a couple of servers setup using CentOS 5.5 with Apache and MySQL. Basically, I will be running it from home.

I have looked into many articles and I should be able to start in about 30 days.

Questions:

What is the best approach to make a frontpage that looks similar to Fox News or any similar websites where you have news categorized, breaking news first, other news displayed based on limit set by admin, etc?

In terms of photos or videos, does anyone know of such components already made to speed up my development?

Any inputs would be appreciated. As I already mentioned, I will start working within 30 days and will be posting my advances and problems.

Comment: Best approach to make a page that looks similar to fox news page is to download the css and html of fox news and make changes to suit your need.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I will probably do that and change it accordingly. My main problem though was in terms of generating content that looks similar based on foxnews idea, not necessarily HTML and CSS structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you want to do is create a bunch of elements in cake that each display a different part of the front page. you can have a look at some examples like

https://github.com/infinitas/infinitas/tree/dev/core/modules

http://teknoid.wordpress.com/2008/12/16/how-to-build-a-dashboard-for-your-application-in-cakephp/